Increasing Triplet Subsequence: Issue with the accepted answer by LeetCode
I was looking at a number of O(n) complexity based solutions for this problem. A lot of people solved this problem in the following way which is accepted by LeetCode:
class Solution:
    def increasingTriplet(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return False

        i = float('inf')
        j = float('inf')

        for num in nums:
            if num <= i:
                i = num
            elif num <= j:
                j = num
            else:
                return True

        return False

I am wondering why this would be the correct solution? This approach does not care about increasing indices of the increasing elements. The precondition is that the triplet indices (i,j,k) have to be i<j<k and num[i]<num[j]<num[k]. This solution violates the first rule.
Let's test with a test case:
nums = [3, 8, 1, 5, 2, 0, 10, 12]

This outputs TRUE for the triplet 0, 2, 10 where i=5, j=4 and k=6.
Could anybody help me if I am missing something basic in the questions?
I appreciate your help.
For this test case, there are 9 triplets according to my understanding.The first one would be: i=0, j=1, k=6 for which the corresponding triplet is: 3, 8, 10

Can you repeat the actual Leetcode question and provide a link?

Are you familiar with the O(N log N) solution to the longest increasing subsequence problem? This is the exact same idea, just hard coded for length 3.

Given the input [3, 8, 1, 5, 2, 0, 10, 12], you are right that i == 0, j == 2 and num == 10, when the function returns True.
You seem to conclude that this means its saying the "the triplet 0, 2, 10" meets the criterion, but that's not what the function is doing.
The naming of i and j in the function are unfortunate, given the text in the question (assuming you mean this one):

Given an integer array nums, return true if there exists a triple of indices (i, j, k) such that i < j < k and nums[i] < nums[j] < nums[k]. If no such indices exists, return false.

What the function does, it tracks the smallest number it has found so far in i and the smallest number it has found so far with a smaller number before it in j. If it finds a number that is greater than j (and it will certainly be greater than i), this implies that there must exist three indices i, j, and k for which the requirement holds, and so it returns True.
By the time it reaches 10 in your example, it has seen 0 as the smallest (i) and 2 as the smallest with a smaller one before it (j, the smaller number being 1). So, it's essentially reporting (1, 2, 10) as the success.
A clearer naming would perhaps have been:
class Solution:
    def increasingTriplet(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return False

        smallest = float('inf')
        smallest_with_smaller_preceding = float('inf')

        for num in nums:
            if num <= smallest:
                smallest = num
            elif num <= smallest_with_smaller_preceding:
                smallest_with_smaller_preceding = num
            else:
                return True

        return False


It does makes sense what you are saying. I was just not convinced with when the function returns true. But yes, it returns TRUE faster by just only caring if there is a triplet that satisfies the conditions.

Yeah, that's exactly it.

The problem is to report whether there's an increasing triple in the array. In this solution i is the smallest element found so far, and j is the smallest element so far that has a smaller element appearing before it. i and j and num aren't the values in the triple, although j and num will be part of an increasing triple.
